# Laravel - Update a table using Maatwebsite Excel Import based on condition

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel

Using Laravel-5.8 and Maatwebsite-3.1, I have a table called employees (Employee).

```
class FirstEmployeeSheetImport implements ToModel, WithBatchInserts, WithHeadingRow, SkipsOnError, WithValidation, SkipsOnFailure
{
   use Importable, SkipsErrors, SkipsFailures;

   public function model(array $row)
   {           
      $this->department = $row['department'];        
      $employee_data = [
        'employee_code'                     => $row['employee_code'],
        'company_id'                        => Auth::user()->company_id,
        'email'                             => $row['official_email'],
        'department_id'                     => $this->getDepartment(),
     ];                
     $employee = Employee::create($employee_data);                   
   }

   public function getDepartment(){
    if(!empty($this->department) || !$this->department){

        return HrDepartment::where('dept_name',$this->department)->where('company_id',Auth::user()->company_id)->pluck('id')->first();
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
  }              
}
```

I want to use the excel upload to update these two (2) fields: email and department_id for each of the employees where:

company_id = Auth::user()->company_id AND employee_code = $row['employee_code'].

Also, it should only perform the update for those that meet the condition. I should only perform update and don't crete.

How do I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: ToModel will insert into database automatically, use ToCollection or ToArray instead

Comment: @AnuratChapanond - How do I achieve that? Kindly show me a sample from my code. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ToCollection` to get your data into `$rows` then update your data accordingly.

```
class FirstEmployeeSheetImport implements ToCollection
{
    public function collection(Collection $rows)
    {
        foreach ($rows as $row) 
        {
            Employee::where('company_id', auth()->user()->company_id)
                ->where('employee_code', $row['employee_code'])
                ->update([
                    'email' => $row['email'],
                    ...
                ]);
        }
    }
}
```